# Mailkit timing out when sending CAPABILITY with IMAPS for 1 user, but not for the other

Tags: imap, exchange-server-2010

My company is using Mailkit for a dedicated client program. Unfortunately the developer has left the company and no source code is available.

So when running with user EP the mailkit.exe *debug* version of the program in order to fetch emails via IMAPS/port 993, it times out after a while. Luckily an output file is generated giving the following:

```
Connected to imaps://imaps.company.net:993/
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * BYE
Connection is closed. 13
```

On the same server using the account AD it works right away; log file is giving the following:

```
Connected to imaps://imaps.company.net:993/
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: A00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed.
C: A00000001 AUTHENTICATE NTLM
S: + 
C: TlRMTVNTUBLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA=
S: + TlRMTVNTUABLABLABLABLABLABLABLAkCGYaTeJuisCQAAAAAAAAAANYA1gBGAAAABgGxHQAAAA9SAFoALQBTAFUARQBEAAIADgBSAFoALQBTAFUARQBEAAEAHgBSAFoAUwAtAEUAWABQAEMALQBWADAAMQA5ADcAMgAEACIAcgB6AC0AcwB1AGUAZAAuAGIAYQB5AGUAcgBuAC4AZABlAAMAQgBSAFoAUwAtAEUAWABQAEMALQBWADAAMQA5ADcAMgAuAHIAegAtAHMAdQBlAGQALgBiAGEAeQBlAHIAbgAuAGQAZQAFACIAYQBkAC0AcgBvAG8AdAAuAGIAYQB5AGUAcgBuAC4AZABlAAcACAAoo1GGWF/RAQAAAAA=
C: TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIwAAAAYABgApAAAAAAAAABAAAAATABMAEAAAAAAAAAAjAAAAAAAAAC8AAAAAYIIAGwAZgBzAHQAYQBkAC0AZQBwAHMAdwBlAGIALQBhAHUAcwB0AGEAdQBzAGMAaABAAHMAdABtAGkALgBiAGEAeQBlAHIAbgAuAGQAZQBMgR43Q5lU3gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAX+a5JGYqTMiuhZBjMz/tOXbxffNW9azQ=
S: A00000001 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
C: A00000002 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: A00000002 OK CAPABILITY completed.
```

Between client and a load-balanced/clustered Exchange Server 2010 a firewall sits.

Using

```
openssl s_client -connect imaps.company.net:993/
```

and entering

```
A00000000 CAPABILITY
```

later on gives no error for both user accounts, instead **BOTH** time out after a while with the following message:

```
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
* BYE Connection is closed. 13 read:errno=0
```

Note: The problem appears by sending

```
A00000000 CAPABILITY
```

within mailkit.exe **BEFORE** authentication takes place.

What is going on here? Why is it working with user AD and not with user EP on the same computer?

Comment: Is your Exchange server simply overloaded? Is your firewall dropping packets? Could you have a bad hub/switch?

Comment: Not sure, I can follow you. If one user works all times and the other never - how can it be an overload of the Exchange Server, respectively a bad hub/switch? Note that tests for both users always took place during the same minute. By looking at a Wireshark trace I could not see any dropped packets. Respectively the firewall is out of my control...

Comment: How much time elapses between the connection and sending the `CAPABILITY` command?

Comment: Add -crlf to your openssl command. It doesn't use \r\n by default which is required for IMAP.

Comment: @jstedfast: 90 sec. To make things more difficult: On a different computer (being in the same subnet/domain) both user accounts work. I could not find any differences between both devices...

Comment: @MAX: When adding -crlf I receive the following error after adding A00000000 CAPABILITY: "A00000000 CAPABILITY" (without ""). Doing the same with no -crlf returns right away "* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed.
* BYE Connection is closed. 13" (without ""). So I wonder, whether -crlf is really needed here?

Comment: This sounds like something you might need to talk to your Exchange server admin for. Alternatively, you could try http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same issue. We suspect a firewall issue to be the cause but that is yet unconfirmed.

What worked for us was an upgrade to the latest version (1.10.0) of MailKit and use the connect overload

```
ImapClient.Connect(servername, port, SecureSocketOptions)
```

using SecureSocketOptions.None to bypass the STARTTLS request.